# Tcl error invalid command name :invalid command name ".27722296"

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, pycharm

The error info:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\user\programs\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1537, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:/u2/projects/skeleton/practice/Boom/Main.py", line 89, in verifex
    n.config(text="Uploading Info")
  File "F:\user\programs\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1326, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "F:\user\programs\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1317, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
TclError: invalid command name ".27722296"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This was the error which appeared after calling one of my functions
:

**The error occurs in this part of the function:**

```
def verifex():
    try:
        global Access, n, im
        im.config(state=DISABLED)
        n.config(text="Uploading Info")
```

The error occurs when calling

> n.config

statement in my function

Comment: I found the answer .

Comment: Actually i destroyed it somewhere above in the code and was not able to find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TclError: Invalid command name ".27722296"` means that you are trying to configure a widget that has been destroyed.

This could be due to one of a couple of causes: Somewhere in your code you are destroying the widget referenced by `n`, or you are creating more than one instance of `Tk` in your program and you're trying to use one instance to kill a widget from another instance.